# How to perform local requests between Sinatra apps

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra, rack

I've got two Sinatra apps mounted through `Rack::URLMap`. One is mounted in the root (`/`), the API, and the other one is on `/frontend`, the Frontend.

My question would be how to make requests from the Frontend to the API? Or just communicate between them without having to make HTTP requests (because in my current environment, that could lead to `ECONNREFUSED` because the hostname may differ from the one in development).

I could work with being able to get the current valid host and port for the apps too, so I fallback to make HTTP requests.

Comment: My initial thought is: If they're not separate, why are they mounted separately? If they are separate, then get the client to make the request.

Comment: @iain well, they're separate. The API has been there for longer, and the frontend is just a simple client for it. I guess I'll have to make requests from the client to the API.

Comment: I have done this before. I just don't remember when and where or even how. I do remember I had to use Rack directly. Could have been a call function. Do check the Rack docs.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#triggering-another-route But now that I see it it might not be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to write a local request class. It just figures out the current protocol + host + port (since the other app is in the same host) and then makes HTTP requests to it, and then I use it from the frontend with helper methods I wrote in the class. Thanks anyways, the clues led me to this in the end!